# Redirect fails to remove www

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm trying force everything to https and eliminate www.  I know this has been hashed over and over - but I'm trying to understand why this version - in particular - is not working.  When I add the above code to htaccess, the force https works great - but it does not remove the www.  How is that even possible given the explicit url that I'm using in the rewriterule??  I've tried removing cache, different browser, different machine, etc.  Could there be something else at the server level overriding it?  tx

Comment: "How is that even possible" - Are you suggesting that even when you access `http://www.example.com` (note the HTTP), it still doesn't remove the `www`? If you access `https://www.example.com` (with `s`) then nothing will happen since your `RewriteRule` is only processed when accessed on port 80.

Comment: Well you hit it on the head, I did not realize the implication of the Port 80 - obvious newb at this - so per your expectation, your first example did work - but once I saw the https working, I merely focused on the www portion.  I appreciate your definitive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to do both i.e. `http->https` and `remove www`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Make sure to keep this rule as first rule and clear your browser cache.

Comment: While w3dk technically answered my question in regard to why my code wasn't working as expected, this is a better (and more transportable) alternative to my original code, works well and is the only answer I can actually vote for - thanks again for the help